Summation of a series with a given $n^{th}$ term
Let $$S_{n} = \frac{4}{3} + \frac{4 \ \mathtt{x} \ 2^4}{15} + \frac{4 \ \mathtt{x} \ 3^4}{35} +\frac{4 \ \mathtt{x} \ 4^4}{63} +....$$ upto $n$ terms then find the value of $33\{S_{16}\}$ where {.} reperesents the fractional part. I have found the general term to be $$\frac{4n^4}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$ but I am not able to proceed further.

Welcome to math SE. Could you edit your post to include some of your thoughts? Mathjax will be useful.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Please provide some Approach to your question. As it's mentioned {$16$} is $0$, where {.} Denotes the Fractional Part of $x$. Your question is not at all clear to me

It seems the dot $4.2^4$ is multiplication... $4(2^4)$ ??

@IITRoorkee, I think your edit (or someone's edit before you) has made the question meaningless. The fractional part is no longer in the question, even though it says ${.}$ means fractional part:)

Note: The question by OP has been edited to something else now. I will post an answer to the original question which was clearer to me: What is $33 \{S_{16}\}$, where $\{.\}$ is the fractional part.
We can write the $n^{th}$ term as $\frac{4n^4}{4n^2-1} = n^2+\frac14+\frac{1}{4(4n^2-1)}$.
$n^2$ is always an integer and summing up $16$ terms will also result in an integer.
$\frac14$ after summing up $16$ terms will also be an integer.
We are left with $\frac{1}{4(4n^2-1)}$ to be summed up for $16$ terms.
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{4n^2-1} = \frac{k}{2k+1}$$ by telescoping.
Therefore after $k=16$ terms, the sum of our desired terms is $\frac{k}{4(2k+1)} = \frac{16}{4 \ \mathtt{x} \  33} = \frac{4}{33}$.
So $33 \{S_{16}\} = 0$
